# How to increment a variable in Scss with a for loop?

Tags: variables, compilation, interpolation, sass

Pretty sure this isn't possible with Sass/Scss but want to be certain that this is a limitation of Sass rather than my own misunderstanding of the syntax...

I'm trying to create a list of styles where each list item gets a different color assigned from a bunch of variables:

```
$color1: #FF0000; // Red
$color2: #FFBF00; // Orange
$color3: #FFFF00; // Yellow
$color4: #7FFF00; // Green
$color5: #007FFF; // Light Blue
$color6: #00FFFF; // Cyan
$color7: #0000FF; // Blue
$color8: #7F00FF; // Purple
$color9: #FF00FF; // Magenta

@for $i from 1 through 9 {
a[href^="link#{$i}"] { color: $color#{$i};
}
}
```

However, the Sass won't compile. I'm thinking it's just not possible to increment the variable name in this manner. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create variable names in a dynamic way, but you can achieve this with even better semantics and flexibility:

```
$red        : #FF0000;
$orange     : #FFBF00;
$yellow     : #FFFF00;
$green      : #7FFF00;
$lightblue  : #007FFF;
$cyan       : #00FFFF;
$blue       : #0000FF;
$purple     : #7F00FF;
$magenta    : #FF00FF;

$colors: $red $orange $yellow $green $lightblue $cyan $blue $purple $magenta;

@each $color in $colors {
  $i: index($colors, $color);
  a[href^="link#{$i}"] { color: $color; }
}
```

**UPDATE:** In Sass 3.3, you can use a map for less repetition.

```
$colors: (
  red        : #FF0000,
  orange     : #FFBF00,
  yellow     : #FFFF00,
  green      : #7FFF00,
  lightblue  : #007FFF,
  cyan       : #00FFFF,
  blue       : #0000FF,
  purple     : #7F00FF,
  magenta    : #FF00FF,
);

@each $name, $color in $colors {
  a[href^="link#{$name}"] { color: $color; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks. Yes, I was aware of doing it with lists but was wondering whether it could be done dynamically. That answers the question definitively though (any other readers should be aware that Eric is a Compass core team member and creator of the fabulous Susy compass plugin). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just came to use an amended version of Eric's code. It just needs to be amended to use `@each` instead of `@for`. Therefore:
  

    $red        : #FF0000;
    $orange     : #FFBF00;
    $yellow     : #FFFF00;
    $green      : #7FFF00;
    $lightblue  : #007FFF;
    $cyan       : #00FFFF;
    $blue       : #0000FF;
    $purple     : #7F00FF;
    $magenta    : #FF00FF;
    
    $colors: $red $orange $yellow $green $lightblue $cyan $blue $purple $magenta;
    
    @each $color in $colors {
      $i: index($colors, $color);
      a[href^="link#{$i}"] { color: $color; }
    }

Comment: Updated to reflect this correction. Thanks @BenFrain!